# MaterialAlertDialog shifts text after showing dialog

Tags: android, material-components-android, material-dialog

When I present a `MaterialAlertDialog`, the text is shifted to expand to the available space, after the dialog is shown.

How do I prevent this from happening (i.e. the text should be static once the dialog is shown)?

Here is a video of what it looks like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a62iG2xNvw0

And here is my code:

```
 MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
        .setTitle(context.getString(R.string.import_file))
        .setMessage(context.getString(R.string.import_file_message))
        .setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.continue_string)) { dialog, _ ->
            dialog.cancel()
            continueClicked()
        }.setNegativeButton(context.getString(R.string.cancel)) { dialog, _ -> dialog.cancel() }
        .show()
```